# Infinite loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I am working on a project where I have to do a random planning of 144 lawyers. This planning is per month.So on every day of a month will have 3-4 lawyers. This planning will be made at the beginning on every month. This planning must be random and every people to be picked-up equally.

My idea is like this: first time I picked up four people each day([144/31]=4) and the remaining 20 to be planned on 01-20 May. There are 4 plans and every lawyer choose on which plan they will participate. In my database I store in a table every option. For example, if he opts for plan 1 ( called `politie_parchet_all`), he will have 1 in table from database).

The problem is here ...This code run just the `if` clause,and the remaining 24 people remain non-selected.I think don't exit from the `if` clause and I don't know why?

```
$str_date ="01-".$luna."-".$an;
$start_date = strtotime($str_date);
$end_date = strtotime('+1 month',$start_date);

$number_days = date("t",$start_date);
$nr_lawyer =number_lawyer($planificare);   

while ($nr_lawyer >0) 
{
    $nr_lawyer =number_lawyer($planificare);
    if($nr_lawyer > $number_days)
    {
        $nr = intval($nr_lawyer/$number_days);

        while ($start_date < $end_date) 
        {
            $time=date('Y-m-d',$start_date);

            for ($i=1; $i<=$nr; $i++)
            { 
                $time=date('Y-m-d',$start_date);
                selectare_avocat($planificare,$time);
            }
            $start_date = strtotime('+1 days',$start_date);
        }
    }
    else if($nr_lawyer < $number_days)
    {
        $str_date ="01-".$luna."-".$an;

        $start_date = strtotime($str_date);
        $end_date = strtotime('+'.number_lawyer($planificare).' days',$start_date);
        echo date('Y-m-d',$end_date);
        while ($start_date < $end_date) 
        {
            $time=date('Y-m-d',$start_date);
            selectare_avocat($planificare,$time);
            $start_date = strtotime('+1 days',$start_date);
        }
    }
    $nr_lawyer = number_lawyer($planificare);
}
```

`selectare_avocat` is a function that will select a random lawyer, store this random lawyer in the `generare_liste` table and update `select = 1`

`select = 0` means that he can be selected. If a lawyer is selected they will not be selected again until the all lawyers have been picked up.

selectare_avocat() function : <- this function work well.

```
function selectare_avocat($planificare,$time) {
    global $con;
    $sql3="SELECT avocat.id from avocat  WHERE avocat.select=0 AND avocat.".$planificare." = 1 AND avocat.id NOT IN (SELECT id_avocat FROM generare_liste WHERE `data` LIKE '{$time}') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
    $id = $row['id'];

    $sql4="INSERT INTO generare_liste(id,id_avocat,planificare,data)VALUES(null,".$id.",'{$planificare}','{$time}')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
    $sql2="UPDATE `avocat` SET `select`=1 WHERE id={$id}";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
}
```

The problem is that this script never ends and remains blocked just on the `if` clause (because after running I have just 124 lawyers in `generare_lista` table) and the remaining 20 lawyers that must be picked up with the `else` clause.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is currently very broad. As a general piece of advice, I would suggest querying the database less often. You could probably retrieve all the ids at the start, use `shuffle` on the array of ids and assign them one by one to each day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is:

get count of day in actual month => $number_days = date("t",$start_date);
initialize a variable 
    $cont = 1;
create a empty array 
    $list = array();
do a loop in your array of data until it's empty;
do 
    $list[$cont] = some random value from your array data, then remove it from array data;
test if 
    $cont is greater than $number_days, then turn it to 1 
increment 
    $cont++;

this routine fits for any count of lawyers.